# No sha256sum in MacOS

Tags: software-installation, osx, hashsum, macports

I tried to use `sha256sum` in High Sierra; I attempted to install it with `MacPorts`, as:

```
sudo port install sha256sum
```

It did not work.

What to do?

Comment: Duplicate of question on Ask Different [Need a cli to check the sha256 hash of a file](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/230917/need-a-cli-to-check-the-sha256-hash-of-a-file/230920#230920). TLDR; macOS has command `shasum` built in, and can use 256 as an option.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

After investigating a little, I found a ticket in an unrelated software in GitHub [sha256sum command is missing in MacOSX](https://github.com/ESGF/esg-search/issues/84) , with several solutions:

- installing coreutils

  ```
  sudo port install coreutils
  ```

  It installs `sha256sum` at `/opt/local/libexec/gnubin/sha256sum`
- As another possible solution, using `openssl`:

> ```
> function sha256sum() { openssl sha256 "$@" | awk '{print $2}'; }
> ```

- As yet another one, using the `shasum`command native to MacOS:

> ```
> function sha256sum() { shasum -a 256 "$@" ; } && export -f sha256sum
> ```

Answer (score 148):

The CoreUtils package is also published [as a Brew formulae](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/coreutils). So if you have Brew installed you can also just run:

```
brew install coreutils
```

Then add `PATH="/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"` to `~/.bashrc`, run `source ~/.bashrc` and you're done.

Comment: Congrats on your first answer in U&L. I prefer MacPorts to Brew, but yes, it is a viable alternative.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer!

Comment: @Milkncokiez If someone manages to convince me why a macports question ought to have as a correct answer a brew solution I am all ears.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro the OP didn't ask how to do get `sha256sum` using MacPorts specifically, they just said they attempted to get it using MacPorts. I found both answers very useful.

Comment: @krookedking The question is tagged Macports, and I am the OP. ;-P Both answers are welcome and useful, it was just a tongue and cheek answer to a particular comment above.

Comment: Note that after `brew install coreutils` installation you will get a message like `Caveats: Commands also provided by macOS and the commands dir, dircolors, vdir have been installed with the prefix "g"`.

Comment: Looks like it is now installed into /opt/homebrew/bin.

Answer (score 14):

If you just need a CLI command, simply

```
shasum -a 256 <file>
```

solves the problem. It is not necessary to install `coreutils`.

This is mentioned, though not prominently visible, in the comment to this question and also in Rui F Ribeiro's answer.

Answer (score 6):

Supplemental Answer to Mig82's, whose answer handles the g-prefix for all executables in coreutils. I offer a tightly-scoped solution.

After coreutils installing with

```
brew install coreutils
```

`ls /usr/local/bin/gsha*`
will list the g-prefixed executables:

- `/usr/local/bin/gsha1sum`
- `/usr/local/bin/gsha224sum`
- `/usr/local/bin/gsha256sum`
- `/usr/local/bin/gsha384sum`
- `/usr/local/bin/gsha512sum`

The solution is to create symbolic links to the ones you want using non-prefixed names (handling all carries the risk of breaking some programs that rely on BSD executables)

Example

```
shaarray=(\
/usr/local/bin/gsha1sum
/usr/local/bin/gsha224sum
/usr/local/bin/gsha256sum
/usr/local/bin/gsha384sum
/usr/local/bin/gsha512sum
)
function installsha() {
  for i in "${shaarray[@]}"
  do
    printf "$i\n" | perl -pe 'printf $_; s/gsha/sha/' | xargs -n 2 ln -s
  done
}
```

Answer (score -1):

## Linux Command (sha256sums)

If you're looking for an alternative to this

```
sha256sum --check SHA256SUMS
```

## MacOS Command (shasum)

Then use this instead on MacOS

```
shasum --algorithm 256 --check SHA256SUMS
```